# Error When upload Yii Website for online

Tags: php, web, yii, hosting

When i upload my Yii website to idwebhost i have problem like this

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'cieprod1_ubay'@'ngasem.idwebhost.com' (using password: YES)
```

My config in `main.php`:

```
'db'=> array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=cieproduction.com;dbname=cieprod1_dbmabak',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'cieprod1_ubay',
        'password' => 'XXXXXXXX',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        ....
    );
```

I dont know what is wrong :(

Comment: Uhm, I would HIGHLY advise you to change your password, now that you've posted it for the entire internet to see.

Comment: Show us more code please, including the code where you connect to the database and **please** remove your password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `host=localhost` or `host=127.0.0.1` instead of `cieproduction.com`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your MySQL db host on cieproduction.com, and you're trying to access from **ngasem.idwebhost.com**. So, you should grant privileges for user **cieprod1_ubay** from host **ngasem.idwebhost.com** to access your database **cieprod1_dbmabak**. This user on a MySQL server is "presented" as `cieprod1_ubay`@`ngasem.idwebhost.com`. The MySQL grant query looks like:

```
grant all on cieprod1_dbmabak.* to `cieprod1_ubay`@`ngasem.idwebhost.com`;
```

Or try to contact the hosting admin to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
'db'=> array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cieprod1_dbmabak',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'cieprod1_ubay',
        'password' => 'XXXXXXXX',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        ....
    );
```